What is the point of 'static const' here? Why is the result absurd without it?
I cannot fully grasp the problem with code I wrote below. It should work perfectly according to my logic but it does not. And it produces a strange result like '52428'. My first question is: Where exactly does this result come from? Where does the conversion process take place to reveal this number?
To solve this, I need to add 'static const' to the private variables of the 'warrior' class. And the problem is solved magically. My second question is: What exactly does 'static const' do here and solve the problem? And what other way can be followed to solve this problem other than 'static const'?
1: definition.h:
#pragma once

typedef unsigned short uns;

2: Hp.h:
#pragma once
#include "definition.h"

class HP {
private:
    uns maxHp;

public:

    HP(uns mHP) {
        maxHp = mHP;
    }
    uns getHP() { return maxHp; }

};

3: States.h:
#pragma once
#include "definition.h"

class STATES {
private:
    uns BStrength;
    uns BIntellect;

public:
    
    STATES(uns bstr, uns bint) {
        BStrength = bstr;
        BIntellect = bint;
    }

    uns getStrength() { return BStrength; }
    uns getIntellect() { return BIntellect; }

};

4: Warrior.h:
#pragma once
#include "definition.h"
#include "States.h"
#include "Hp.h"

class Warrior : public HP, public STATES {
private:
    uns hp = 100;
    uns Strength = 20;
    uns Intellect = 5;
public:
    Warrior() : HP(hp), STATES(Strength, Intellect) {}


};

5: main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "Warrior.h"


int main()
{
    Warrior warr1;
    Wizard wiz1;

    std::cout << warr1.getHP() << " " << warr1.getStrength() << " " << warr1.getIntellect() << "\n";

    
}

The result:
52428 52428 52428
2.1: Warrior.h with static members:
#pragma once
#include "definition.h"
#include "States.h"
#include "Hp.h"

class Warrior : public HP, public STATES {
private:
    static const uns hp = 100;
    static const uns Strength = 20;
    static const uns Intellect = 5;
public:
    Warrior() : HP(hp), STATES(Strength, Intellect) {}


};

The second result:
100 20 5

The initialization order, the parent HP is initialized first, Warrior::hp is not yet and used uninitialized. Enable all and extra compiler warnings.

Initialization order. The base-classes are initialized before non-static members.

Composition, instead of inheritance, would avoid this issue here.

Do you want Warrior to have both (non-static members) Strengh and BStrengh?

The problem is simply that your data members are uninitialzed when you are passing values to HP and STATES:

class Warrior : public HP, public STATES {
private:
    uns hp = 100;
    uns Strength = 20;
    uns Intellect = 5;
public:
    Warrior() : HP(hp), STATES(Strength, Intellect) {}
};


Base classes are always initialzed before the data members in a class, meaning that at the point where HP(hp) runs, hp does not have any value.
What you are doing is undefined behavior.
Note that the default member initializer = 100 is evaluated after HP(hp).
Also note that any compiler should give you a warning in that scenario, as long as you just enable them. See also Why should I always enable compiler warnings?
Adding static const to hp coincidentally solves the problem because hp is given a value in that case, prior to HP(hp) running.
However, each Warrior then has the same hp, which is clearly not what you want.
A possible solution looks as follows:
class Warrior : public HP, public STATES {
private:
    static constexpr uns DefaultHp = 100;
    static constexpr uns DefaultStrength = 100;
    static constexpr uns DefaultIntellect = 100;

    uns hp = DefaultHp;
    uns Strength = DefaultStrength;
    uns Intellect = DefaultIntellect;
public:
    Warrior() : HP(DefaultHp), STATES(DefaultStrength, DefaultIntellect) {}
};

Note that use of static const with an initializer (e.g. = 100) is discouraged because it's a very weird, special case in the C++ language, and it doesn't even provide a definition for DefaultHp.
